# Problem when I generate smaller rectangles using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to reduce the size of the rectangles, see in the image below that they are large. If I adjust `xmin` , `xmax` , `ymin` and `ymax` in  `geom_rect` to smaller values, for example, `.2`, the figure was unformatted, the rectangles are separated. How to proceed?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- bind_rows(
  expand_grid(x = 1:5, y = c(1, 2.2)),
  expand_grid(x = 8:12, y = c(1, 2.2))
) %>%
  arrange(y, x) %>%
  mutate(
    num = c(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0), c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0)),
    fill_color = ifelse(row_number() %in% c(c(11,12,13,14,15), c(16,17), c(8,9,10)), "skyblue", "white")
  )

ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = x - .5, xmax = x + .5, ymin = y - .5, ymax = y + .5, fill = fill_color), color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = num)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.5, xend = 2.5, y = .4, yend = 2.8), arrow = arrow(length = unit(5, "pt"))) +
geom_segment(
    aes(x = 5.7, xend = 7.3, y = 1.6, yend = 1.6),
    linewidth = 3, lineend = "round", linejoin = 'round', color = "black",
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(9, "pt"), type = "open")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("skyblue", "white")) +
  ylim(0, 4) +
  xlim(0, 13) +
  theme_void() + theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "pt"),
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the rectangles to be smaller without changing their relative separation, you don't need to change the `xmax = x - 0.5` section, you need to change the x and y values in the original `df` which defines the 'corner' coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option could be by changing the limits using `coord_cartesian` to make the graph look smaller like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = x - .5, xmax = x + .5, ymin = y - .5, ymax = y + .5, fill = fill_color), color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = num)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.5, xend = 2.5, y = .4, yend = 2.8), arrow = arrow(length = unit(5, "pt"))) +
geom_segment(
    aes(x = 5.7, xend = 7.3, y = 1.6, yend = 1.6),
    linewidth = 3, lineend = "round", linejoin = 'round', color = "black",
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(9, "pt"), type = "open")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("skyblue", "white")) +
  theme_void() + theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "pt"),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 15),
                  ylim = c(0, 5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>